# Upgrading portage on gentoo fails

Tags: gentoo

upon `emerge portage`, got following error:

```
/var/tmp/portage/sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62/temp/environment: line 2273: /dev/fd/62: No such file or directory
 * ERROR: sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62 failed (install phase):
 *   directory does not exist: /var/tmp/portage/sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62/image/usr/lib64/python3.2/site-packages
 *
 * Call stack:
 *     ebuild.sh, line   93:  Called src_install
 *   environment, line 2300:  Called python_compileall '/usr/lib64/python3.2/site-packages'
 *   environment, line 2235:  Called die
 * The specific snippet of code:
 *       [[ -d ${d_image} ]] || die "directory does not exist: ${d_image}";
 *
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62/work/portage-2.1.11.62'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62/work/portage-2.1.11.62'

>>> Failed to emerge sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62, Log file:

>>>  '/var/tmp/portage/sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62/temp/build.log'

 * Messages for package sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62:

 * ERROR: sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62 failed (install phase):
 *   directory does not exist: /var/tmp/portage/sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62/image/usr/lib64/python3.2/site-packages
 *
 * Call stack:
 *     ebuild.sh, line   93:  Called src_install
 *   environment, line 2300:  Called python_compileall '/usr/lib64/python3.2/site-packages'
 *   environment, line 2235:  Called die
 * The specific snippet of code:
 *       [[ -d ${d_image} ]] || die "directory does not exist: ${d_image}";
 *
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62/work/portage-2.1.11.62'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62/work/portage-2.1.11.62'
```

synced it before today. any ideas?

Comment: This `directory does not exist: /var/tmp/portage/sys-apps/portage-2.1.11.62/image/usr/lib64/python3.2/site-packages` should have tipped you off. But such questions would be better suited at the [Gentoo forums](http://forums.gentoo.org)

Comment: @fuero - there's no harm in asking it here; after all if we just sent everyone to the products forums there would be no content here...

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your current python version installed (usually solved selecting 2.7)

```
eselect python list
eselect python set python2.7
```